# Jersey 403 forbidden error

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have a simple api :

```
@Path("/application")
public class MyClass {

    @PUT
    @Path("/one/{name}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @Produces("application/json")    
    public Response firstApi(@PathParam("name") String name,
            @Context ContainerRequestContext crc) {
        //my code
    }
```

I am using `Glassfish` `4.1`

I have some knowledge for working with `Jersey` but I never faced such error, so I am not understanding what is exact reason of this cause.

I am making api request as follows :

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/application/one/myname
```

Please help me to understand this behavior. I am using `jersey` version `2.22`.

Comment: Are you just entering the URL in a browser? PUT isn't supported that way. Try doing the request using cURL or similar utility

Comment: Sir I am using advanced Rest Client.

Comment: OK just wanted to check.

Comment: I tried to debug , but my request is not entering at-least in the filter.

Comment: I think this is because put method is not supported by your browser by direct hitting url

Comment: I have another project which is working perfectly fine. I have copied the whole project and made changes to the function in my new project and this project giving me 403 error.

Comment: Want to be sure: where is the route (class or method ) for `ProjectName`?

Comment: Have you tried adding a request property to the URL connection object?

Comment: Sorry Sir , I did not understand what you want to say.

Comment: Done. I created new web.xml and pom.xml files and now it is working even though I kept the content same in the new file.Thank you all of you.